# iOS - implicit conversion loses integer precision 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
size_t subsetBytesPerRow, subsetHeight, subsetWidth, subsetHeight;
```

Method calling:

```
(new GreyscaleLuminanceSource(subsetData, subsetBytesPerRow, subsetHeight,
                              0, 0, subsetWidth, subsetHeight));
```

Method declaration:

```
GreyscaleLuminanceSource(unsigned char* greyData, int dataWidth, int dataHeight,
      int left, int top, int width, int height);
```

getting this **warning** `'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'`. How to fix this one?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the type declarations to int:

```
int subsetBytesPerRow, subsetHeight, subsetWidth, subsetHeight;
```

In the event that this just trades off one set of warnings for another, you could change the type back to `size_t` and then cast each parameter to `int` in your call to `GreyscaleLuminanceSource`.